# Update appsettings.json value in .net core with Azure Devops

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-deployment

I'm relatively new in the devops world and I'm trying to help my team since our devops person left.

We are deploying the app without any issue through Github/Azure pipeline,
but when it comes to updating value in appsettings.json file we are not able to do that.

This is a sample of our appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:ourserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sampleuserid;Password=12321321321;"
  },
  "Stripe": {
    "SecretKey": "sk_live_addsd123213312O8756A",
    "WebHookSecret": "whsec_Adsa8sd67i343ij3ij"
  }
}
```

We want to update the SecretKey and the WebHookSecret values for Stripe.

What are our options?

I've read that we can add Azure app settings service task and include the values there, should I do something like this?

[image]

P.S. the values I have for Stripe are just for demo purposes.

Comment: Have you ever set the attribute manually in advance on the azure portal? Navigate to your app, and go **Configuration** => **Application settings**.

Comment: I would suggest using user variables - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch .  App settings is good but if you were to change your target web app, you will have to keep configuring it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Stripe__WebHookSecret` instead of `WebHookSecret`, but this doesn't update your appsettings.json. It will set setting in Web App Configuration which overrides values from file if they are defined in the portal. Which is correct approach. Definitely better than updating file.

You can also try use `Stripe:WebHookSecret` - please check this [site](https://tehremo.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/override-connection-strings-app-settings-in-asp-net-core-and-azure-app-service/).